# Since the death of an actor X. Y has elapsed ten years

Tags: grammar

Could you please help me to rewrite this sentence.

*Since the death of an actor X. Y has elapsed ten years.*

I want to use the relative clause.

*An actor X. Y., of whom death has elapsed ten years.*(I suppose that this sentence is wrong.)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "Actor X died 10 years ago", "Since the death of actor X ten years ago, ...", etc.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to create the relative clause. Actor, since whom/whose death… I am not sure what kind of structure to use.

Comment: Show me the complete sentence you're trying to construct. Are you looking for "Actor X, who died 10 years ago, was a great man...", or "Actor X, whose death ten years ago came as a shock to many", etc?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're looking for "Since the death of Actor X, *ten years have passed*"?

Comment: Actor X. Y. died ten years ago. So it has elapsed ten years since his death. I would like to make the relative sentence: Yes I can say Actor X. Y. whose death came 10 years ago… But is possible this sentence: Actor X. Y., from whose death elapsed 10 years, (…), or An actor X. Y., since whom death has elapsed ten years, (…).

Comment: Can you fill in the ...s for me? I would like to see the complete sentence, to find the best matching clause.

Comment: I am just trying to create a complete sentence.

Comment: Well, I gave you a number of phrases which can be used to create complete sentences, while also expressing the period of time since the death of the actor. None of them appear to suit your need, and to diagnose that, I need more information. I think the most useful information would be the actual, specific, complete sentence you're trying to create, so that I can plug in my previous suggestions and see why you feel they may not work, and use that feedback to find one which would. Otherwise, the previous suggestions, which you don't like, are all I can offer.

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me. Just let me pose the last question:
Is this sentence grammaticaly OK?

Actor X. Y., since whose death have elapsed ten years, was known for his great performance in the movie A.

Comment: No, you'd want to say (as I did above in the comments, and oerkelens did below in an answer): "Actor X. Y., since whose death *10 years have elapsed*, was known for his great performance in the movie A".

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the first sentence needs rewriting because your verb (has elapsed) does not correspond to the subject (ten years). Also, "an actor X.Y." feels strange: *an actor* indicates you don't know which one it was, but then you know their name and when they died. So let's write that sentence as:

> Since the death of actor X, ten years have elapsed. He is remembered fondly.

"I want to use the relative clause." OK, but you cannot stuff those ten years in a relative clause about actor X like you tried to! You can convey the same meaning as your original sentence as follows:

> Actor X, since whose death have elapsed ten years, is remembered fondly.

However, a shorter, more to-the-point version that I feel flows a bit more naturally, would be:

> Actor X, who died ten years ago, is remembered fondly.

"of whom death has elapsed ten years" => here, you try to make *death* the subject of *elapse*, but it is not. It is *the years* that have elapsed, not the death! I guess this is the reason as well why you wrote *has* instead of *have* in your original sentence.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and corrections. So this sentence is not possible:

Actor X. Y., since whose death have elapsed ten years, was known for his great performance in the movie A.

Comment: That is actually also possible. It is very wordy though, and doesn't as natural as _who died ten years ago_. But as such, grammatically, there is nothing wrong with it. I added this construction to my answer, it is closer to the original sentence :)